# How to make gulp-concat work with stream from gulp-run?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

## Background

I'm making a custom style for [MyAnimeList.net](http://myanimelist.net/) with Stylus, using Gulp as build system. For final stylesheet I need to:

- Generate some CSS by running an external program (.exe) that writes to `stdout`, which I'm using [`gulp-run`](https://github.com/cbarrick/gulp-run) for.
- Concatenate output from Stylus compiler and this auto-generated CSS, which I'm having problem with.
- Add prefixes with Autoprefixer and minify resulting CSS (which works fine on separate files)

## Problem

Using [`gulp-concat`](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat) on streams produced by gulp-run crashes with exception (*Streaming not supported*). Using [`vinyl-buffer`](https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-buffer) or [`gulp-streamify`](https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-streamify) makes it fail silently instead. I couldn't find a way to make `gulp-run` work with `gulp-concat` or `gulp-concat-css`

If possible, I would like to avoid creating temporary files.

#### Sample Gulpfile.coffee

None of these tasks generate 'example.txt' in build folder.

```
gulp         = require 'gulp'
run          = require 'gulp-run'
concat       = require 'gulp-concat'
streamify    = require 'gulp-streamify'
buffer       = require 'vinyl-buffer'

gulp.task 'fail_plain', ->
  run('echo Merged').exec()
    .pipe concat 'example.txt' # exception is thrown
    .pipe gulp.dest 'build/'

gulp.task 'fail_streamify', ->
  run('echo Merged').exec()
    .pipe streamify concat 'example.txt'
    .pipe gulp.dest 'build/' # no file written to output

gulp.task 'fail_vinyl_buffer', ->
  run('echo Merged').exec().pipe buffer()
    .pipe concat 'example.txt'
    .pipe gulp.dest 'build/' # no file written to output
```